# Window.open with variable url ---I tried and tried and tried - Please point me in the right direction

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is my script - I can open a new popup page but I cannot get my variable of the field Play to show.
My button is on each line named play and I want to on click - go the the field named - Play -bring in the content as the u r l and open popup.  my real site is 
   http://www.laurelcoc.com/lcc/lccabc/p/donindex.php to see in action Thank you Don

```
 $(document).on('click', '.play', function(){
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   var Play = $(this).attr("Play");

   window:open("[$Play]","LCCMM"," top=150, left=100,height=400, width=400, 
   scrollbars=no, resizable=yes,toolbar=no");
   });
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with `ajax`? `window:open`? `"[$Play]"` this is not PHP.

Comment: The code on your site does not work for a few reasons. First, $(this) is resolving to the button itself, not the row. You can tell because if you put a console.log($(this)), you'll see that it prints the button. Play is undefined because the button has no Play attribute. Second, $Play is incorrect. It should be window.open(Play, "LCCMM"...

Comment: thank you for your responses!  I did start with ajax and I have tried a lot of different ways.

Comment: $sub_array = array();
 $sub_array[] = '<div contenteditable class="update" data-id="'.$row["id"].'" data-column="Speaker">' . $row["Speaker"] . '</div>';
 $sub_array[] = '<div contenteditable class="update" data-id="'.$row["id"].'" data-column="Title">' . $row["Title"] . '</div>';
 $sub_array[] = '<div contenteditable class="update" data-id="'.$row["id"].'" data-column="Play">' . $row["Play"] . '</div>';
 $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="play" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs play" Play="'.$row["Play"].'">Play</button>';
 $data[] = $sub_array;
}

Comment: I would appreciate any help thank you!